# Can apps developed with react-native runs in background (when minimized) of IOS devices? Does apple allow to do it with react-native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, background-process

I want to create a application using react native to run in the background of ios when the user leaves the application screen, not when exit the app. It's a Bluetooth LE related task. Does anyone knows how to work on that. Help me with it.

I tried to use react-native-background-timer, but it didn't work.

Comment: Core Bluetooth is one of the supported background modes.  You will need to find a react package that can work with core Bluetooth. Timers are not going to be part of the solution.